# Data not getting inserted into the gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a gridview for which I insert data based on rows. I have written `onInsertCommand` for that which is like below

```
protected void GridFirst_InsertCommand(object sender, Obout.Grid.GridRecordEventArgs e)
{
    int iRowCount = 0;

    if (ObjPriCon.State == System.Data.ConnectionState.Closed) ObjPriCon.Open();

    ObjPriCmd = new OracleCommand("select STAT_TYPE, ref_no, ref_date, stat_7_12 from XXCUS.XXACL_PN_AGRMT_GRD where mkey = '" + StrMkey + "'");

    if (Session["DtFilldata"] != null)
    {
        DtFilldata = (DataTable)Session["DtFilldata"];
    }
    else
    {
        BindDatatable();
    }
    iRowCount = DtFilldata.Rows.Count;
    DataRow newRow = DtFilldata.NewRow();
    newRow["SR_No"] = iRowCount + 1;
    newRow["STAT_TYPE"] = Convert.ToString(e.Record["STAT_TYPE"]);
    newRow["REF_NO"] = Convert.ToString(e.Record["REF_NO"]);
    newRow["REF_DATE"] = Convert.ToString(e.Record["REF_DATE"]);
    newRow["STAT_7_12"] = Convert.ToString(e.Record["STAT_7_12"]);

    DtFilldata.Rows.Add(newRow);
    GridFirst.DataSource = DtFilldata;
    GridFirst.DataBind();
    AddToViewState();
}

private void BindDatatable()
{
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    DataRow dr;

    DataColumn SR_No;
    DataColumn STAT_TYPE;
    DataColumn REF_NO;
    DataColumn REF_DATE;
    DataColumn STAT_7_12;

    DtFilldata = new DataTable();

    SR_No = new DataColumn("SR_No", typeof(Int32));
    STAT_TYPE = new DataColumn("STAT_TYPE", typeof(String));
    REF_NO = new DataColumn("REF_NO", typeof(String));
    REF_DATE = new DataColumn("REF_DATE", typeof(String));
    STAT_7_12 = new DataColumn("STAT_7_12", typeof(String));

    DtFilldata.Columns.Add(SR_No);
    DtFilldata.Columns.Add(STAT_TYPE);
    DtFilldata.Columns.Add(REF_NO);
    DtFilldata.Columns.Add(REF_DATE);
    DtFilldata.Columns.Add(STAT_7_12);

    GridFirst.DataSource = DtFilldata;
    GridFirst.DataBind();

}
```

Except `SR_NO` my any data is not getting inserted. I dont know what's wrong here. Even I am not getting any errors.

**Update**

`Page_load` code.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Request.QueryString["Mode"] != null && Request.QueryString["Mode"] != "")
    {
        strMode = Request.QueryString["Mode"];
        HidMode.Value = Request.QueryString["Mode"];
    }
    if (Request.QueryString["Key"] != null && Request.QueryString["Key"] != "")
    {
        StrMkey = Request.QueryString["Key"];
        HidCefMkey.Value = Request.QueryString["Key"];
    }

    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        Session["DtFilldata"] = null;
        //GridSecond.Visible = false;
        //GridThird.Visible = false;
        //GridFourth.Visible = false;
        //BindGrid1();
        BindGrid2();
        BindGrid3();
        BindGrid4();
    }
}
```

Comment: is the SR_NO value is 1 . ?

Comment: @FakeisMe: yes, it is `1`

Comment: does `Obout.Grid.GridRecordEventArgs e` passes the right records?

Comment: @DDDSoft: yes, it does. as I have used it several times

Comment: DtFilldata row count is coming zero. so you are getting SR_NO as 1 but not other values?

Comment: @FakeisMe: Okay, so where is my mistake.. help me out

Comment: disable viewstatemode of grid  and see. or debug and see if the GridRecordEventArgs  e has value ?

Comment: @FakeisMe: No, I am not getting any records in `e` .. now what should I do.

Comment: I have not worked OBOUT grid before. but what i understand is the InsertCommand  Event fires when you add a row in the grid , that is the only way the event will have row values . If it is already added to the table in the grid  then why to add new datasource ? and add tht row to it ? . Add record to the exisitng datasource .

Comment: @FakeisMe: See for this first time there is no record into the table. SO i am inserting whole new record.. still it is not getting inserted

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123702/discussion-between-fakeisme-and-nad).